# How to solve the problem of ntp "Unable to contact time server" from KDE?

Tags: networking, kde, opensuse, ntp, ntpd

I want to set date and time automatically but this error appears when I try to .. I'm using openSUSE, I tried different servers but it didn't work either, help please!

[image: Error Window]

It doesn't seem to be a network problem:

```
$ ping pool.ntp.org
64 bytes from 41.78.128.17: icmp_seq=1 ttl=41 time=260 ms
```

To the question of whether ntpd is installed and running:

```
$ ps -C ntpd
PID TTY TIME CMD
```

i.e. there's no ntpd process running.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep ntp
yast2-ntp-client-3.1.12-1.7.noarch
ntp-4.2.6p5-25.2.1.i586
```

Further information from the comments:

```
$ sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org 
25 Sep 19:41:51 ntpdate[3162]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Comment: I don't use KDE or SUSE, so I might not be able to help, but -- can you run `ntpdate pool.ntp.org`? I suspect you're unable to get NTP traffic over the network.

Comment: I tried `sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org` and the output was `25 Sep 19:41:51 ntpdate[3162]: no server suitable for synchronization found` @JeffSchaller

Comment: Seems that something is blocking NTP traffic (port 123) for you. Do you have a host-based firewall? A network-level firewall? You can also try the -v (verbose) and -u (unprivileged source port) options for more information.

Comment: What version of opensuse?

Comment: @TopHat Actually that was a long time ago. I don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, your specified NTP Server works for me (Moldova and UK)

```
$ ntpdate -qu 41.78.128.17
server 41.78.128.17, stratum 2, offset 0.003619, delay 0.22984
25 Sep 19:26:35 ntpdate[13226]: adjust time server 41.78.128.17 offset 0.003619 sec
```

so it's not a problem with the server. At least, not obviously.

Remember that the pool servers are all run voluntarily and several IP address ranges are blocked by a large number of operators to mitigate the unreasonable hundreds or even thousands of queries per second from those blocks. Turkish Telecom is one that springs to mind, for example.

You might want to try different servers from the command line. Some suggestions are `1.uk.pool.ntp.org`, `2.uk.pool.ntp.org`, and `3.uk.pool.ntp.org`. Replace the `uk` with your two-letter country code for more variety. For a specific instance that I know works, try my own server:

```
ntpdate -qu ntp.roaima.co.uk
```

If none of these work then you need to look to your own server for potential firewall rules blocking the traffic:

```
iptables -nvL
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the tardy addition on this topic.  Hopefully, this helps someone at some point.

I'd like to add that additionally, one can check to see if the ntpd service is running  from the command line similar to below (for Linux distributions which utilize the System V init system and many others which provide emulation and/or aliasing of):

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo service ntpd status
ntpd (pid 8374) is running...
```

If running you can stop the service by:

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo service ntpd stop
Shutting down ntpd:                                           [  OK  ]
```

This was performed on the below Linux version:

```
[user@host ~]# cat /etc/version
2017 1 PCLinuxOS
```

With the below frontend/GUI versions:

```
[user@host ~]$ kde4-config --version
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.18
kde4-config: 1.0
```

Note: you can use the --version parameter with any "standard" KDE program such as Konsole, Kate, Konqueror, etc.  The same can be achieved in the GUI by selecting drop-down menu Help -> About KDE.

I ran into the same issue where the ntpd service, which was active on my workstation, was preventing the GUI from handshaking with the external public NTP service configured in the widget [KDE Date & Time Control Module] thus resulting in the error you (and I both) received.